# pikepdf - how to return in memory pdf object from django view

Tags: python, django, pdf, pikepdf

I currently have the following code:

```
pdf = Pdf.open(f"cover.pdf")
page = pdf.pages[0]
for i, a in enumerate(page.Annots):
    print(a.T)
    a.V = str(i)

pdf.save("output_test.pdf")
```

I can't find anywhere online that describes how to return the in-memory pdf object from a django view.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-pdf/

Comment: @ArakkalAbu that doesn't answer my question... and I have no idea why this question is getting downvoted?? To use BytesIo would mean some really dodgy code that loads a pdf, makes a copy and then clones each page and append onto bytesio pdf

Answer (score 1):

So after looking at pikepdf source code, save() takes a binary stream. So the following worked for me:

```
in_mem = BytesIO()
self.new_pdf.save(in_mem)

response = HttpResponse(in_mem.getvalue(), content_type=get_content_type("pdf"),)
response["Content-Disposition"] = getStringContentDisposition("test.pdf", True)
return response
```